# Active Directory - Find Mac OS X workstations

Tags: macos, active-directory, dsquery

I'm hoping someone can help me with a way to query Active Directory to return just a list of Mac OS X workstations.

Answer (score 2):

After you launch "Active Directory Users and Computers" on your Windows Server, you can create a filter with the following steps:

**1.** Click "View" from the menu bar

**2.** Select "Filter Options..." from the drop down list

**3.** Select the radio button labeled "Create Custom" and the click "Customize"

**4.** Click "Field" and from the drop down choose "Computer" then "Operating System"

**5.** "Condition:" should be "**Starts with**" and "Value:" should be "**Mac**"

**6.** Click *Add* and then *OK*.

Now when you choose the AD folder containing your computers, only the computers with "Mac" at the beginning of their Operating System name will show.

**To shut off this filter**, follow steps **1** and **2** but choose "Show all types of objects" instead of "Create Custom". You can also use the icon in the menu bar that looks like a funnel to get "Filter Options" instead of using the menu bar. Be sure to shut off the filter after you have found the information you are using. This will save the later freak out of "Where did all the computers go?" when you or someone else logs in looking for a non Mac OSX computer.